# Using angular and MVC Partial Views

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am very new to angular so forgive my brevity/ignorance.

What I want to do is use `angular` in an `ASP.NET MVC partial view` that is loaded dynamically.  So I have a page with a button and when that button is clicked, I go out and get a partial view and inject that `HTML` into a `DIV` on that page.

In this partial view I want to use angular.  I want a div with an `ng-controller="MainController as main"`,  a few `{{main.Field1}}` and `{{main.Field2}}`'s, and a script that will create the controller and set these field values.

The trouble is that the partial view isn't compiled/parsed/linked/whatever for `angular` and my controller method is never hit.

I have seen references throughout my searches to `$compile()` and using directives but they seem to involve more complicated templates and whatnot and I have yet come across a bare-bones stripped down simple solution for what I want to do.  Can someone provide one?

Comment: It's not clear how you load this partial. There shouldn't be any issues if you use any number of angular approaches the are built in such as using `templateUrl` in router or custom directive, or using `ng-include`

Comment: Try to use routing to achieve that. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$compile` service as below:

```
angular.module('application',[])
.controller("TestController", ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile){
    var self = this;    

    self.OnShowCompiledHTML = function(){
        var html = '<div data-ng-controller="OtherController as vm"><span>{{name}}</span><button data-ng-click="vm.OnShowFullName()">Show Full Name</button></div>';
        var templateElement = angular.element(html);
        var scope = $scope.$new(true);//pass in isolate as true as we dont need the parent scope
        scope.name = 'John';
        scope.surname='Doe';
        var clonedElement = $compile(templateElement)(scope, function(clonedElement, scope) {
            //attach the clone to DOM document at the right place            
            angular.element(document.querySelector('#container')).append(clonedElement);
       });
    };
}])
.controller("OtherController", ['$scope', function($scope){
    var self = this;    

    self.OnShowFullName = function(){
        alert('This is my fullName:' + $scope.name +' ' + $scope.surname);
    };
}])
```

You can find a working example here https://jsfiddle.net/87h02o8r/

**Explanation:**

`$compile` takes an element, and an instance of `$scope`. To create a new scope on the fly you can use the `$scope.$new(isolate, parent)` method.
`$scope.$new(isolate, parent)` takes two parameters.

The first parameter indicates if you want to create a scope that inherits from the parent scope, if not you are creating isolated scope.

If you create a scope that inherits from the current scope, you need to pass in the current scope eg  `$scope.$new(false, $scope)`;

Because the HMTL is now complied you can use the `OtherController` as normal;

This is a handy method of injecting compiled HTML if you need to fetch the un-compiled partial views of bootstrap Modals or any other partial HTML functionality.

Instead of hard-coding the HTML like I did, you will fetch the HTML via the `$http` service.

Comment: Thanks!  This gets me most of the way there.  I would like to, however, in this case, create OtherController in a script in the html string, not in the parent page.  I've tried this but I get "OtherController is undefined".  In my case I am doing a $.get() to get the partial view (represented by the html string in your example) and this partial view contains all the angular scripting.

Comment: How does your script tag look like in your partial?

Comment: Instead of having the controller script in the partial HTML, can you not include the script in a script file in the MVC bundling?

Comment: @Dan please remember to mark as the answer if this was helpful.

Comment: I did end up going this route, mostly, and I did simplify my life a bit and included the controller script in the parent page.